# Canonical Transformations in Quantum Field Theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, unitarity

In his [lecture notes](http://www.sa.infn.it/Massimo.Blasone/documents/cantrans.pdf) on canonical transformations in quantum field theory, Massimo Blasone defines the *boson translation* transformation to be

\begin{equation}
a_k \rightarrow a_k(\theta) = a_k + \theta_k
\end{equation}
for $\theta_k\in\mathbb C$, and notes that the transformation can be thought of as the action of some operator $U(\theta)$:
$$a_k(\theta) = U(\theta) a_k U^\dagger(\theta) = a_k + \theta_k$$
$$U(\theta) = \exp[iG(\theta)]$$
$$G(\theta) = -i\int d^3k \left(\theta^*_k a_k - \theta_k a^\dagger_k\right)$$

He goes on to say that because the $a_k(\theta)$'s do not annihilate the vacuum $|0\rangle$, we must define a new vacuum state $|0(\theta)\rangle$ such that $a_k(\theta)|0(\theta)\rangle = 0$.  In terms of the old vacuum, we have

$$|0(\theta)\rangle = U(\theta)|0\rangle = \exp\left[-\int d^3k |\theta_k|^2\right] \exp\left[-\int d^3k \ \theta_k a^\dagger_k\right] |0\rangle \tag{*}\label{*}$$

and so

$$\langle 0 | 0(\theta)\rangle = \exp\left[-\int d^3k |\theta_k|^2\right] $$

which means that if $\int d^3k |\theta_k|^2 = \infty$ then $\langle 0 | 0(\theta)\rangle = 0$. This then means that this transformation leads out of the original Hilbert space and that the new representation of the CCRs is unitarily inequivalent to the original one.

---

My question is regarding \eqref{*}.  It seems strange to me that the two exponentials can be split in that way - if the integral in the first exponential evaluates to $\infty$, would not that just kill the entire state?  Should it not instead be written

$$ |0(\theta)\rangle = \exp\left[-\int d^3k \left( |\theta_k|^2 + \theta_k a^\dagger_k\right)\right]$$

instead?

---

Related:
[Unitarily Inequivalent Representations](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/200305/unitarily-inequivalent-representations)

Comment: I made a minor edit to your question and I don't understand why that silly thing popped up in the middle. I liked the question and since it wasn't answered...If you try to edit you see the full question. What has happened?

Comment: ? In what way is the final expression different than ( * ) for constant  *θ*s?

Comment: @CosmasZachos If I recall my line of thought correctly, it was that if $\int dk |\theta_k|^2\rightarrow \infty$, then the first term on the right hand side of (*) would evaluate to 0, and so $|0(\theta)\rangle  = U(\theta)|0\rangle = 0$.  Perhaps this was the entire point, but at the time I thought that perhaps by keeping the integral intact, the second term would act as a regular for the first, such that the operator as a whole would not annihilate $|0\rangle$.  In hindsight, I suspect I simply misunderstood the point, but I'd have to read those notes again to be sure.